# JS failure in Firefox but fine in IE

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have below method which is working fine in IE but I am getting the following error:

> TypeError: hdnButton .click is not a function

when I use it in Firefox.

```
function PopupTest() {
    var hdnButton = document.getElementById('div_btn').firstChild;
    hdnButton.click();
}
```

Could anyone suggest how to get over this issue? I am not able to find any solution for it.

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle showing the error?

Comment: Error which I am getting in firefox is "TypeError: hdnButton .click is not a function".

Comment: I believe you are using `jQuery` plugin?

Comment: Can I have any solution for this issue please?

Comment: Wow Dude, can you just answer the questions above instead of complaining ? It has been less than 25 minutes since you asked your question. Could you please - at least - give us your html ?

Comment: some HTML sample would definitely help here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My *guess* (since you've shown no html) is that you have some white space (perhaps a line break) which IE is ignoring, but which FF is returning as a text node. If so, you should be able to skip over it with something like:

```
function PopupTest() {
    var hdnButton = document.getElementById('div_btn').firstChild;
    while (hdnButton.nodeType === 3)
        hdnButton = hdnButton.nextSibling;
    hdnButton.click();
}
```

...which works by using the [`.nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeType) property to test whether the `.firstChild` is a text node (`3` means text node; for more information see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeType)). If it is, it takes the next sibling and tests its `.nodeType`, and so on until it finds an element that isn't a text node. (Of course this assumes there will be one.)

Alternatively if you know what tag the (non text node) first child should be you could select it on that basis, e.g., if it's actually a `<button>` element:

```
hdnButton = document.getElementById('div_btn').getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
hdnButton.click();
```

Or if you don't need to support IE<=7:

```
document.querySelector("#div_btn > :first-child").click();
```

Comment: One question. what is the purpose of hdnButton.nodeType === 3. I mean why only you have used 3?

Comment: I've updated my answer to explain in more detail, but basically `.nodeType` of `3` means text node, and text nodes are what you want to skip past.

Comment: Be careful to explicit text node skip (type 3). Because it will not skip other "side" nodes such as comments. Look at this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/pg2py/3/ I would rather advise to follow the W3school notice there http://www.w3schools.com/dom/prop_element_firstchild.asp (they do bascially the same test as nnnnnn but take different than 1 instead of similar to 3.)

Comment: Good point @Zzirconium. I rarely have comments scattered around my html so I didn't really think about that. Though in any case I'd be much more likely to use the `.querySelector()` method in which case I believe comments would not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check if document.getElementById('div_btn').firstChild;

if it exists, maybe there is another error such a whitespace, or you are calling PopupTest() before the DOM is loaded.

Try:

```
<body onload="PopupTest()">
```